# Making an indexentry for '+' when '+' is the quote sign for makeindex

Tags: indexing

The `makeindex` manual suggests using the `+` as a quote sign rather then `"` if one uses german sorting. Now `makeindex` seems to get confused if I have a real `+`that is supposed to go to the index. How can I get a `+` into the index or a string that starts with a `+`.

Comment: Are you using `\index{$+$}`? You can sort it in *p*, for example, using `\index{plus@$+$}`.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I guess all `+` get removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a single `+` into the index, it must be masked with `++`, a double `++` will be `++++` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\blindtext

Foo \index{foo}


\blindtext[5]

Foobar \index{foobar}

\index{"Hello"}
\index{++}
\blindtext
\index{++$\sqrt{2}$}

\printindex


\end{document}
```

`mygerman.ist`

```
quote = '+'
```

Call `pdflatex foo.tex ; makeindex -s mygerman.ist -g foo`

[image]